# What do you mean with.... vs What do you mean by

Tags: word-choice

Yes, the title is correctly expressing my question,
so which one of these :

> 1. What do you mean with that?
> 2. What do you mean by that?

Question :
i've been wondering which one of them that sounds more natural, at least like a native speaker would use.

Comment: The choice of preposition depends on the phrase following it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question, unfortunately the choice of preposition now depends on what *that* refers to.

Comment: Prepositions vary by dialect, but I think that *by* is Standard English in that usage. To my ear, *with* would be substandard. It's either *what do you mean by that*, or *what do you mean **to do with** that?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a basic question, "*What do you mean by that?*" is grammatical and idiomatic and means "Please explain the meaning of (or possibly *justify*) your previous statement more fully".

On the other hand, "*What do you mean **with** that?*" as a question by itself is completely unidiomatic, and would never be said by a native speaker.

Comment: I strongly disagree. It can be an elided form of "What do you mean **to do** with that?"  As when your friend comes over holding a pick-axe.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=X2REzS9phAMC&pg=PA92&dq=%22you+mean+with+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yI2aUseVFMPXoATesoK4BA&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22you%20mean%20with%20that%22&f=false

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=elcotAo5Y40C&pg=PA79&dq=%22you+mean+with+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yI2aUseVFMPXoATesoK4BA&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22you%20mean%20with%20that%22&f=false

Comment: I agree with Matt. It may be okay in some dialects, but it's not grammatical in "standard" English. Some silly book doesn't prove anything. The author could have made a typo, or the characters are using some dialect or whatever.

Comment: If you want to prove something using books, try [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+mean+by+that%2C+you+mean+with+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20mean%20by%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20mean%20with%20that%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Kaz +1. Authors make basic mistakes all the time; just because something is written down by a self-appointed author doesn't make it idiomatic. Otherwise I could claim that "a elephant" rather than "an elephant" is grammatical because of http://books.google.com/books/about/Imagine_Me_As_a_Elephant.html?id=e12GPQAACAAJ and http://books.google.com/books?id=qYcNFyIuFfcC&pg=PA69&dq=%22a+elephant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r5yaUuevMs3poATA5oHIBA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=%22a%20elephant%22&f=false :)

Comment: @kaz wow. If it may be okay in "some" dialect then it is incorrect to say that no native speaker would say that,eh?  We all know that native speakers rarely speak perfect, standard English 100% of the time.

Comment: @matt. I'd wager that those are proofs that some native speakers would say those things.  One clearly an uneducated author, and one an author writing in the voice of an uneducated character but native speakers both.

Comment: @Jim "it may be okay in some dialect" means "it's not okay for english learners". In the context of ELL, you do not have a point, I'm afraid. If a non-native speaker uses "what do you mean with that", it will be automatically attributed to poor learning of English, rather than brushed away as some dialect.

Comment: @Kaz-  [Where do you think I found those books?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you%20mean%20with%20that%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)  And just because the *by* usage is **far** more common, doesn't mean the other usage is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Jim: Some native English speakers say all kinds of things that aren't even vaguely grammatical - see my links where some authors think that "a" is the correct article to use with "elephant" as an example. I dispute the fact that "what do you mean with that" is a dialect though. It's just people making a mistake.

Comment: I never said it was a dialect- that was Kaz.  Also since *that* is a pronoun, which can be the object of a preposition I think the sentence is perfectly grammatical, it's simply not a mainstream usage.  Remember that OP asks for something a native speaker would use, not what the Society for the Enforcement of Proper English" would bless for inclusion in their textbook.

Comment: @Jim: I agree that it is grammatical, and I'll edit that in to be more clear. It's just completely unidiomatic and sounds like a learner making a mistake rather than a dialect or valid alternative way to say "What do you mean by that?". If the OP wants to sound like a native, he'd be better off sticking to what 99.99% of native English speakers actually say, rather than emulating the mistakes of the 0.01% of native speakers.

Comment: @Jim I can't imagine that possibly being elided. I had the same thought as you initially, but if someone said *what do you mean with that,* or even *what do you mean with that remark*, I'd question their level of proficiency in English. That's a pretty abstract way of looking at it (or a subtle nuance that'd be lost on most speakers).

Answer (score 1):

"What do you mean with that" can be grammatical (in standard English) if it is a question about quoted speech:

> What do you mean, "with that"? With what?

But

> What do you mean with that?

is avoided by speakers. A Google [n-gram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20you%20mean%20by%20that,do%20you%20mean%20with%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,do%20you%20mean%20by%20that;,c0;.t1;,do%20you%20mean%20with%20that;,c0) pf "do you mean with that" versus "do you mean by that" gives some evidence that "do you mean with that" is very rare. Furthermore, it doesn't mean anything different and can be replaced by "what do you mean by that".

It's rare enough that those who don't use it and haven't heard it will regard it as wrong or as some regional dialect, and if a non-native speaker uses it, it will be seen as a non-native mistake.

Note also that some of the matches for "do you mean with that" include sentences having forms such as "Which Mary are you going with? *Do you mean, with that* girl from across the street?" which is not what we're interested in. An "n-gram" is just a string of words.